# Globally defined RingBuf does not work inside the loop() function

Tags: logging, arduino, avr, arduino-c++, teensy

I can use a `RingBuf` from the `SdFat` library only inside the `setup()` function and I don't understand why. Can `RingBuf` and `File32` be defined as global and configured only once during the setup? I'm working on Teensy 4.1.

For instance, this code works

```
#include "sdios.h"
#include "SdFat.h"
#include "RingBuf.h"

#define SD_CONFIG  SdioConfig(FIFO_SDIO)        // Use Teensy SDIO

File32  stateFile;
RingBuf<File32, 5> outRingBuff;

// SETUP function
void setup() {
  SdFat32 sdCard;
  bool retValBool;
  
  Serial.begin(9600);                 // Teensy serial is always at full USB speed and buffered... the baud rate here is required but ignored

  Serial.println("Initialization SD card START");

  // SD Initialization
  if (!sdCard.begin(SD_CONFIG)) {
    sdCard.initErrorHalt(&Serial);
    Serial.println("ERROR SD Initialization failed!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Initialization SD card DONE");

    // Output file opening
    retValBool = stateFile.open("aa.csv", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

    // Output file opening
    if (retValBool) {
      outRingBuff.begin(&stateFile);
      
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');

      size_t numBytes = outRingBuff.writeOut(4);

      Serial.println(numBytes);

      outRingBuff.sync();
      stateFile.sync();
      stateFile.truncate();
    }
  }
}

// LOOP function
void loop() {
      Serial.print("loop");

      delay(800);
}
```

But this code does not work, without retrieving any kind of compiler errors, warnings etc

```
#include "sdios.h"
#include "SdFat.h"
#include "RingBuf.h"

#define SD_CONFIG  SdioConfig(FIFO_SDIO)        // Use Teensy SDIO

File32  stateFile;
RingBuf<File32, 5> outRingBuff;

// SETUP function
void setup() {
  SdFat32 sdCard;
  bool retValBool;
  
  Serial.begin(9600);                 // Teensy serial is always at full USB speed and buffered... the baud rate here is required but ignored

  Serial.println("Initialization SD card START");

  // SD Initialization
  if (!sdCard.begin(SD_CONFIG)) {
    sdCard.initErrorHalt(&Serial);
    Serial.println("ERROR SD Initialization failed!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Initialization SD card DONE");

    // Output file opening
    retValBool = stateFile.open("aa.csv", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);

    // Output file opening
    if (retValBool) {
      outRingBuff.begin(&stateFile);
      
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');
      outRingBuff.write(',');

      size_t numBytes = outRingBuff.writeOut(4);

      Serial.println(numBytes);

      outRingBuff.sync();
      stateFile.sync();
      stateFile.truncate();
    }
  }
}

// LOOP function
void loop() {
      Serial.print("loop");
      
      outRingBuff.write('A');
      outRingBuff.write('A');
      outRingBuff.write('A');
      outRingBuff.write('A');

      size_t numBytes = outRingBuff.writeOut(4);

      Serial.println(numBytes);
      
      outRingBuff.sync();
      stateFile.sync();
      stateFile.truncate();
      
      delay(800);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what compiler errors or warnings are you getting, and what linea of your code do they point out?

Comment: No errors or warnings found. However, I've just discovered that -fpermissive flag is used by default in Arduino IDE. Could it be the reason why It does not raise any error?

Comment: You said "this code doesn't work". It's a little difficult guessing what that means. And, perhaps the flag may cause the lack of error.

Comment: You're right. The code freezes, without doing anything, even the simple println `Serial.println("Initialization SD card START");` in the setup. And then, when I try to upload a new software on the microprocessor, I have to restart the board because it is not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The `SdFat32` object is defined inside the `setup()` function so it is inaccessible inside the `loop()` function. Likely, it is not directly called neither by the `RingBuf` or the `File32` object so it does not retrieve any error, however it is not possible to save data on SD while the `SdFat32` object is not accessible.

In my opinion this behaviour should be fixed, I think an error or warning should be raised.

Comment: The code you showed in your original question has `loop` accessing external variables `outRingBuff` and `stateFile`, both of which are globally defined. The definition of `SdFat32` is global (defined by the header), so you must be talking about the instance of `SdFat32` you have declared in `setup()`, namely, `sdCard`? In `setup()` after your `sdCard.begin()` call you make no further reference to `sdCard`, either in `setup()` or `loop()`. If you were intending to use the SD Card, perhaps that's the issue. All I have to go on is the code you posted. If it's changed, then...